# Implement a hard-coded formula in a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask what is the way to implement and hard-coded formula in a cell using VBA?
In my case my code consist of the following part:

```
Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LiveTV!A:B,2,FALSE),""No Live TV"")"
```

I need to cover the first 2 columns and the range !A:B returns to A:(B) after I run the macro, which obviously is not a working range.

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` should be `ActiveCell.Formula`  You are using A1 nomenclature.

Comment: Also set `Range("T2").Formula` directly, without Select/ActiveCell

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot to both! Have a good day

Comment: You might want to ask a new question. This comment isn't likely to have the same visibility a new question would.

Comment: Use `Workbooks("yourFileNameHere.xlsx")` (for example) and not Windows()   Or post a new question with more info, as suggested by Michael.